# kerberos authentication using javamail

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail, kerberos

I need to configure kerberos authentication between Widows Exchange Server and javamail API. I have doe the fallowing settings. But i am getting **erro**r like:

```
Exception in thread "main" GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:121)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getCredentialElement(GSSManagerImpl.java:192)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSCredentialImpl.add(GSSCredentialImpl.java:406)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSCredentialImpl.<init>(GSSCredentialImpl.java:60)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createCredential(GSSManagerImpl.java:153)
```

Can any one help me how to find kerberos tgt from javamail api.

Comment: I've never tried to use Kerberos from JavaMail, but I think you have to enable SASL support, which can then use the GSSAPI authentication mechanism, which supports Kerberos.  Have you done all that?  After that, it's a question of how the GSSAPI authentication mechanism finds the Kerberos TGT.  [This document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/sasl/sasl-refguide.html#GSSAPICLNT) might help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I enabled GSSAPI. And now my doubt is do i have to run kinit tool from command prompt and generate the ticket and pass it from jaas.conf or Javamail internally takes cares of running kinit tool every time. i tried both still no use